# static resource from ${catalina.home} in spring boot war

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my Spring MVC project I had

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/, file:${catalina.home}/myresources/" />
```

configured to serve static resources from multiple locations.
In Spring Boot however,

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/", "file:${catalina.home}/myresources/");
    }
}
```

is not working as expected. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @Configuration
public class ResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ResourceConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        String catalinaHome;
        try {
            catalinaHome = System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e);
            catalinaHome = "";
        }
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/", "file:" + catalinaHome + "/myresources/");    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't read this property ${Catalina.home} directly in your string. But you can use @Value by following way:

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceConfig implements 
WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Value("${catalina.home}" )
    private String catalinaHome;
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/", "file:" + catalinaHome + "/myresources/");
    }
}
```

Comment: It says: 
`Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'catalina.home' in value "${catalina.home}"`
Do I need anything in application.properties?

Comment: Yes, you do. You need it.

Comment: Need what? I have application.properties file. Do I need to set anything there for your solution to work? is what I meant.

Comment: yep. add this config       catalina.home = "YourHomeHere"

Comment: that is a static solution, isn't it? I was hoping to getting it from the system variables so that I don't have it manually configure it for different environments.

Comment: You can do by following way: in your application.properties catalina.home = ${CATALINA_HOME}

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'CATALINA_HOME' in value "${CATALINA_HOME}"`